# Backing up Time Machine to an external disk also used by other machines - no sparsebundle?

Tags: time-machine

I moved to using an external disk (a Drobo) on 1 machine as a Time Machine backup for all of my machines. I've got 2 of the machines backing up perfectly, but the problem is with the machine that the drive is connected to.

When I start the backup of the directly connected machine, Time Machine creates the folder structure /Backups.backupdb/[computer name]/ instead of just creating another sparsebundle file.

Should I care? If yes, then how do I make Time Machine create a sparsebundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sparsebundle is how Time Machine backs up using the network method. The Backups.backupdb method is how it backs up when the drive is hooked up locally therefore you can't make it create a sparse bundle if its connected locally because that's the way time machine works. If you want it to make a sparse bundle you have to backup through a network. It should not make a difference to you since you'll be accessing it through time machine without having to worry about files etc.

Comment: This is what I thought, but how do I get the machine that's connected directly (FireWire atm) to create a .sparsebundle file?

Comment: It is supposed to create it on its own when you first backup our machine on that particular disk

Comment: Okay...so, now that it isn't, where should I look?

Comment: make sure you don't have machines with same name, it should be in the device you selected to make the backup to.

Comment: Nope, different names (macpro, mbpi7, svn1). Not sure what you mean by "in the device you selected to make the backup to".

Comment: when you open time machine (the preference pane) on the right there is a part where you have to select the drive to backup; the sparsebundle is somewhere in the device

Comment: So, I select the drive using "Select Disk...", select the disk and then "Use for Backup". When it begins backing up for the first time (from that machine) it creates the "Backups.backupdb" folder instead of a .sparsebundle.

Comment: The sparsebundle is how Time Machine backs up using the network method. The Backups.backupdb method is how it backs up when the drive is hooked up locally.

Comment: So, the original question: should I understand that it's normal, but should I care and if I should, then how to get it to make a sparsebundle?

Comment: You can't make it create a sparse bundle if its connected locally because that's the way time machine works.
If you want it to make a sparse bundle you have to backup through a network. It should not make a difference to you since you'll be accessing it through time machine without having to worry about files etc.

Comment: Cool. I'll trust ya. It'd be helpful for the next person if you could it in the answer :) Thanks for all your help!