# Time Machine: many different Macs on one disk?

Tags: time-machine

I'd like to get a 2TB external USB drive and put Time Machine backups for 3 different Macs on it.

Is there any configuration I need to do for this?  Or do I just start a new TM backup on Mac 1, wait till it finishes, disconnect the USB drive, move on to Mac 2 and repeat?

In other words, will Mac 1 take the entire USB disk for itself or something of that nature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sharing a single drive amongst several Macs is doable. For more details, here are some resources to review:

- This [Apple.SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36958/any-side-effects-when-sharing-a-time-machine-backup-disk-between-lion-and-snow-l) may provides some pointers, such as not using File Vault 2 when sharing the drive with Macs running OS X prior to Lion.
- Another [Apple.SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/backing-up-time-machine-to-an-external-disk-also-used-by-other-machines-no-spa?rq=1) provides some suggestions for network backup.
- Other discussions (such as [this post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1072343)) recommend using multiple partitions on the shared drive.